# Force naming convention when adding service reference

Tags: c#, wsdl, visual-studio-2019, naming-conventions, service-reference

I have a WSDL-file which I'm supposed to add to a C#-project in Visual Studio. The WSDL-file is written so that classes and methods that are being automated are not the C# naming convention. For instance a class is called `article` and not `Article` and a method is called `getArticle()` instead of `GetArticle()`.

Is there any way I can get the auto generated code to be forced to use the standard naming conventions?

Comment: Add wrapper classes (data and action classes) for access to wsdl references in C# if you want to change the naming while allowing you to use the auto-generated reference files

Comment: Maybe you can refer the document:[To enforce naming style rules on build, you should instead set the severity by using code rule severity configuration.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules#rule-id-ide1006-naming-rule-violation).